# Have option of Night Mode in GUI in Qt

Tags: qt, user-interface

I have made a GUI with the help of Qt. Now I want to add a button which will enable night mode. On this button click I want that the screen will look something similar to that seen through night goggles. I tried using this.setStylesheet("color code here"); but the problem is my buttons dont respond to their stylesheets as expected and the central stacked widget doesn't show any colors. 
Can anyone suggest me how this color change can be done in Qt?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you sent the stylesheet you are using

Comment: Not doing anything great. Just on button click slot i am writing
this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
this->setStyleSheet("background-color:green);

Is there any other way than stylesheet for doing this?

Comment: @user2548968 you should read Qt documentation first, before trying to adjust the code without understanding what you are doing.

Comment: OK got it...Did it by setting pallete...Works fine that way. Thanks all...

Answer (score 2):

Please, take a look at Qt Style Sheets as it described [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html).

Comment: There is something for QMainWindow in it but its not helping. The separator option is not available.

Comment: @user2548968 You may set stylesheet globaly for your application. And... RTFM! There are next text: "Note: To customize the separator (resize handle) of a QDockWidget, use QMainWindow::separator."