# How to set day and night theme in Qt 5.5 application

Tags: c++, qt

I'm writing an app in Qt. I want that the app switches to a darker ui theme at a given time. What is the best and easiest way to do that?

I was thinking to create 2 different functions on to set the day theme and one to set the night theme. And in those functions just set the specific settings for all visible objects.

Or is this also possible with 2 different stylesheets, and then change between them at runtime?

Comment: what did you try so far? have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18733100/have-option-of-night-mode-in-gui-in-qt?

Comment: Yep, you can set different stylesheets at runtime. You have a lot of examples in the Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have 2 different stylesheets, and load these at runtime:

```
QApplication app(...);
QFile qss_light("lighttheme.qss");
QFile qss_dark("darktheme.qss");

qss_light.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
app.setStyleSheet(qss_light.readAll());
// or
qss_dark.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
app.setStyleSheet(qss_dark.readAll());
```